# Google rejected app because of HostnameVerifier issue

Tags: android, ssl-certificate, android-volley, hostname, android-security

Updated my app to trust all certificates in volley for sdk 17 and below as volley works fine without hostname verifier for higher sdk. It worked fine but google rejected my app update saying

> Your app(s) are using an unsafe implementation of the HostnameVerifier interface.

I am using the following code

```
TrustManager[] trustAllCertsc = new TrustManager[] { new X509TrustManager() {
        public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
            return null;
        }
        public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
        }
        public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
        }
    } };
    SSLContext scc = null;
    try {
        scc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        scc.init(null, trustAllCertsc, new java.security.SecureRandom());
    } catch (KeyManagementException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(scc.getSocketFactory());
    // Create all-trusting host name verifier
    HostnameVerifier allHostsValidc = new HostnameVerifier() {
        public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
            return true;
        }
    };
    // Install the all-trusting host verifier
    HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(allHostsValidc);
```

Answer (score 2):

Delete all of that code. You will fail multiple Play Store checks (`HostnameVerifier` and an accept-all `TrustManager`). Plus, the reason why the Play Store is rejecting your app is because, through this code, *you are weakening app security*.

Comment: But on removing my app won't work on devices less than API 17

Comment: @asishrauto: Either set your `minSdkVersion` to 17, or find some other solution that does not involve weakening app security. For example, if you are trying to use HTTPS with a specific server, and that server's root SSL certificate is not recognized by Android, [teach your HTTP client to trust your server's certificate](https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/HTTPS#customizing-trusted-certificates).

Answer (score -1):

**I wouldn`t recommend to continue development on your app with unsecure HTTP requests**.

However, if you dont care about security at all, you can use the following code instead to work with `Volley` and get approved at `PlayStore`:

```
private static void disableSSLCertificateChecking() {
    TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[]{new X509TrustManager() {
        public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] arg0, String arg1) throws CertificateException {
            // Not implemented
        }

        @Override
        public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] arg0, String arg1) throws CertificateException {
            // Not implemented
        }
    }};

    try {
        SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");

        sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());

        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());
    } catch (KeyManagementException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```